# Avoiding Line Break hassle in copy and paste

Tags: vim

Suppose I have something like this (i have displayed line breaks (new lines) with $)

```
This is line1$
This is line2$
$
This is line3$
```

My objective is to copy line1 and paste it in the empty line (as quick as possible) so that it looks like this

```
This is line1$
This is line2$
This is line1$
This is line3$
```

Unfortunately I am unable to accomplish this. This is what I tried so far
In normal mode the cursor is on line 1 and I press V. As a result the entire line is selected including (line break) $. After that in order to yank it I press `"*y` Now In normal mode I move to the blank line and press "*p as a result I get

```
This is line1$
This is line2$
$
This is line1$
This is line3$
```

I then tried pressing "*P and I get

```
This is line1$
This is line2$
This is line1$
$
This is line3$
```

How can I easily copy and paste to get the result

```
This is line1$
This is line2$
This is line1$
This is line3$
```

I know i could press dd on the empty line to remove it however I wanted to know if there was a more efficent way of doing this (something close to what I am already doing)

Comment: Have you tried `y$`, then `p` on the empty line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `yy` to copy the line you want. Move your cursor onto the empty line and run

```
Vp
```

To visually select the whole line and paste the contents replacing the section.

Comment: Apparently the first two lines are pasted. I just want the first one .Could you explain what the commands do

Comment: @Rajeshwar `yy` copies the current line. `V` visually selects the current line. `p` pastes the copied line. (This shouldn't ever copy two lines. You probably hit `yj` which copies the current line and the next line)

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish what you want, first place your cursor at the beginning of line 1 and press:

```
[shift]y
```

Then move the cursor below line 2 at the beginning of the blank line and press:

```
[shift]p
```

Basically, the `[shift]y` **(normal capital Y)** copies to end of line and `[shift]p` **(normal capital P)** pastes at the current location. Give it a try and let me know if you have issues.

Comment: That does not do the trick. The output is same as the second one when I press "*P

Comment: Wow!  I tried your exact setup and confirmed it worked as you show you expect it to work. I wonder if your `vimrc` settings are causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Without moving your cursor, you could use following construct

```
1t2|norm gJ
```

where

```
1t2      -- Copy line 1 and put it below line 2
norm gJ  -- join next (empty) line and remove trailing space
```

Answer (score 0):

Only with ex commands:

```
/^$/d|1t-

/^$/d    " jump to next empty line and delete it
1t-      " copy the first line above the current line
```